# Setup Cassandra container in Github Actions and query

Tags: docker, cassandra, github-actions, scylla

I have this .yml file:

```
name: CasDB

on: push

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always


jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      cassandra:
        image: cassandra
        ports:
          - 9042:9042
        options: --health-cmd "cqlsh --debug" --health-interval 5s --health-retries 10
    steps:
      - run: docker ps
      - run: docker exec ${{ job.services.cassandra.id }} cqlsh --debug localhost:9042 --execute="use somekeyspace;"
```

I want in my Github actions to spin up a Cassandra database and than execute some queries. The Cassandra database is running, but when I want to execute a query ("use somekeyspace"), it fails with this error message:

> Using CQL driver: <module ‘cassandra’ from
> ‘/opt/cassandra/bin/…/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.11.0-bb96859b.zip/cassandra-driver-3.11.0-bb96859b/cassandra/init.py’> Using connect timeout: 5 seconds Using ‘utf-8’ encoding Using ssl:
> False Traceback (most recent call last): File
> “/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py”, line 2459, in
> main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ)) File
> “/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py”, line 2437, in main
> encoding=options.encoding) File “/opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh.py”, line
> 485, in init
> load_balancing_policy=WhiteListRoundRobinPolicy([self.hostname]), File
> “/opt/cassandra/bin/…/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.11.0-bb96859b.zip/cassandra-driver-3.11.0-bb96859b/cassandra/policies.py”, line 417, in init socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not
> known
> ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.

What things I need to change in my .yml to:

1. Execute a .sql script (multiple database scripts)
2. Execute a single cqlsh statement

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply running `cqlsh` with wrong parameters: You cannot give it `localhost:9042` as the hostname. The hostname and port are separate parameters. Try:

```
cqlsh localhost 9042
```

Instead of `cqlsh localhost:9042`.